# Resizing Oracle Datafiles

Tags: oracle, resize, watermark, fragmentation

I have an Tablespace with 3 datafiles (autoextend enabled). Actually Datafile_1 and Datafile_2 are 32GB in size and Datafile_3 size is 10GB.

I Dropped one huge table and Datafile_2 occupation dropped to 4GB. Using some queries**[1]** over the dba_extents view I could see the HWM was still at 32GB. I was able to move/shrink all the objects at the end of the datafile. Using the same query again i could see the HWM dropped to about 4GB.

Then I tried:

ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '+DATA/myDatabase/datafile/datafile_2' resize 5G;

And got:

ORA-03297: file contains used data beyond requested RESIZE value;

I tried to increase the size until 30GB without sucess.

I did some research and found this article:

http://www.dbi-services.com/index.php/blog/entry/resize-your-oracle-datafiles-down-to-the-minimum-without-ora-03297

Here, instead of dba_extents the author access directly sys.x$ktfbue to view the metadata. His script show that Datafile_2 HWM was still 32G. For some reason MAX(block_id) in sys.x$ktfbue is different from the one in dba_extents.

Well, I did some more research to discover how to map the block_id on x$ktfbue to a database object. Found another script with that. After running it I could see that all the blocks at the end of the Datafile_2 was marked as "free space".

Well, now I am on a situation where I don't know what to do. Maybe having more than one datafile is the problem? Any tips?

**[1]** This is the query:
 SELECT (MAX((block_id + blocks-1)*8192))/1024/1024 "HWM (MB)" FROM dba_extents WHERE file_id=8;

*file_id 8 represents datafile_2

EDIT: Tried one other thing. I created a new tablespace and moved all the objects on Datafile_3 to it. I can see now that Datafile_3 is completely empty via DBA_EXTENTS. Also purged recyclebin.

Then tried to resize it without success(ORA-03297), also tried to drop it and got "ORA-03262: the file is not empty".

Finally I decided to sum all the free extents from Datafile_3 on DBA_FREE_SPACE and compare it to the value at DBA_DATA_FILES. There is a difference of 1MB somewhere! I am going crazy. :)

Comment: Nice question but better suited for the dba group

Comment: Did you try to repair the bitmaps? (dbms_space_admin.tablespace_rebuild_bitmaps;)

Comment: can't help with that but I hope the following could be helpful: if you have blobs being inserted/deleted to really recover the space of the deleted ones you should issue the command `alter table myblobtable shrink space;`